# Unable to trigger Linux kernel page writeback mechanism

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm messing with the Linux kernel (4.14.0), specifically the page cache, but I am unable to trigger the page cache writeback mechanism. I thought that all file I/O goes through the page cache, but the code for writeback doesn't seem to be called. I inserted some printk statements around page_check_dirty_writeback() (mm/vmscan.c around line 930), but none of them seem to show up.

I've tried 2 methods to trigger page writeback. I wrote a program that simply creates a text file and writes to it, and I also tried running `dd if=/dev/zero of=testfile.txt bs=1M count=10 && sync` from https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Page_Cache_Basics.

Am I missing something, is the page cache different in 4.14.0 (am I reading old documentation?) Also, if available, where is the best place to ask questions about the kernel? Is it here?

Comment: I suspect that the above function has something to do with file mappings. `dd` uses `read()` and `write()` without `mmap`ing files. Hence this function is not called.

Comment: try echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_cache

Comment: @gudok I did try reading and writing to `mmap`ed files, but that didn't work either. In theory, all files, even non`mmap`ed ones should go through the page cache, right?

@AlexHoppus what does this do? I tried to edit that file, but it says fsync failed, tried `sudo` too